# shaking between images inside Java?

Tags: android, eclipse, viewflipper

So I have a ViewFlipper that links to a .xml file and when I shake it, it switches images, simple. I want it to switch images inside the java. how would I go about this?
here is my main Java

```
package www.straightapp.com.shakerTest.html;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public  class ShakerTest extends Activity
implements Shaker.Callback {
private Shaker shaker=null;
ViewFlipper flipper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    shaker=new Shaker(this, 1.25d, 500, this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    shaker.close();
}

public void shakingStarted() {
    Log.d("ShakerDemo", "Shaking started!");
    flipper.showNext();
}

public void shakingStopped() {
    Log.d("ShakerDemo", "Shaking stopped!");

}
}
```

thanks
-Chistian

Comment: can u pls add relevant code and more explanation

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but I guess you want [ViewFlipper.startFlipping()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#startFlipping%28%29) and [ViewFlipper.stopFlipping()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#stopFlipping%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

you can get the ViewFlipper reference and use showNext() to flip to next child element.

Comment: Are you sure control is coming to shakingStarted() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [ImageSwitcher class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html), here's its [sample implementation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html).
You can call its APIs based on shake.

Comment: I did look at that before i posted here. it would help for other things, but I don't want to call from a .XML file I want the layout to be created within the Java.